# MySQL/PHP updating a value in a variable number of rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, sql-update

I have an `users` table where I store user info along with a reputation score like Stackoverflow has.

My question is how to update multiple users' reputations with a single MySQL query.

Here's my `users` table

```
user_id  reputation
  1          11
  2         202
  3        3003
  4         444
  5         555
```

Let's say user_id=1 downvotes user_id=4 and user_id=5. In this scenario user_id=1's reputation loses 2 points and user_id=4,5 both lose 10 points.

The `users` table would then look like this:

```
user_id  reputation
  1           9 //lost 2 points
  2         202
  3        3003
  4         434 //lost 10 points
  5         545 //lost 10 points
```

I know the MySQL query shown below works but I'm wondering a generalizable solution in the case that the number of users to `UPDATE` is variable and depends on the voting.

```
UPDATE `users`
 SET `reputation` = CASE
 WHEN `user_id` = '1' THEN reputation - 2
 WHEN `user_id` = '4' THEN reputation - 10
 WHEN `user_id` = '5' THEN reputation - 10
 ELSE `reputation` END
```

Comment: I would create temporary table with your current data. Then do an inner join to update the records at once.
Then again you are faced with the issue of how to define the 'update factor' of your reputation e.g. -2 , -10, +5... so on.


UPDATE 
    tblUsers u JOIN temp_tblUsers t ON (u.ID=T.ID)
SET p.REPUTATION = t.REPUTATION -2;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace the second `WHEN` with an `IN()` clause. It still requires some dynamic query building in your application code, but if your API allows direct binding of arrays into an `IN()` clause, this is much easier.

```
UPDATE `users`
 SET `reputation` = CASE
 WHEN `user_id` = '1' THEN reputation - 2
 WHEN `user_id` IN ('2','3','4') THEN reputation - 10
 ELSE `reputation` END
```

I will admit I find it a bit awkward to force all of this into one query though. Unless performance is a real issue, I would rather see this as two queries wrapped in a transaction - one to subtract `-2` from `user_id=1` and one to subtract the `-10` users.

```
/* Only on InnoDB tables... */
START TRANSACTION;
Update `users` SET `reputation` = `reputation` - 2 WHERE `user_id` = 1;
Update `users` SET `reputation` = `reputation` - 10 WHERE `user_id` IN (2,3,4);
COMMIT;
```

[Documentation on MySQL transaction handling...](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html)

Comment: -@Michael thanks, yes using PHP I can just `implode()` the user_id array to make the string for the `IN` clause. Checking right now to see if your query makes sense within my application...

Comment: -@Michael, i'm not sure what a transaction is. Would you mind including the two queries solution you suggest in your answer?

Comment: @timpeterson Added.  Your way works fine, the logic is just confusing to follow on frist glance.

Comment: In this method how do you tweak it if you have totally different reputation factors to be subscracted?